# Will Google AdMob ban me for using this code?

Tags: android, admob

Recently I am using Google AdMob to show ads on my app. But I am confused.

Here I am using an Interstitial ad on my app where there is a listview and when I click an Item on the listview It takes me to a new Activity,and then shows an Interstitial Ad.

My question is,will Google ban me from Admob If I use the following code cause of the onAdLoaded() function?Also,I'm not going to use test Ads.

I can't understand this.PLEASE HELP!

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class Golpo1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_golpo1);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
                .build();

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }
    public void displayInterstitial() {

        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        } 
    }``
}
```

Comment: If you properly add test device ids,No problem you can continue

Comment: @salihkallai I'm not going to use test ads,Real ads.So will that occur any problem by google?Like banning me?

Comment: If you add test devices, This will load test ads in that device only,But in other devices, it shows real ads,Loading real ads in your test device may ban your admob account(i am not sure), IF YOU WANT TO VIEW THE REAL ADS USE A DEVICE OF SOME OTHER PERSON AND USE ANOTHER PRIVATE NETWORK CONNECTION

Comment: @salihkallai thats not what i meant.I mean I will never use test ads to show real ads cause I am going to put this on google play.But if i use onAdLoaded on the app will google ban me?Not because of test device.

Comment: No problem in your code

Comment: you test adds on the testing device, if you are uploading it to the playstore no need to do anything special, also do not let your adds interfere with normal app usage, some users go crazy and flag your app, you wil be banned

Answer (score 0):

This section of your code is problematic:

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        displayInterstitial();
    }
});
```

You should never attempt to display an interstitial in the `onAdLoaded` callback. Interstitials are meant to be loaded in advance, and then displayed when the flow of the application has reached a natural pause (such as between levels in a game, or after completing an action). The idea is that the ad should wait for the user, so the user never waits for the ad.

Thus, you should be loading your ad somewhere else in your code. :)

See the [AdMob interstitial guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) for details.